# Declare a final variable based on a condition and use it in lambda in java

Tags: java, lambda

I have the below scenario.

I would like to use a variable inside lambda expression. But this variable will be have a onetime value(final) based on a condition.

```
  final String constraintsAmount;
  if(constraint.isPresent()) {
       constraintsAmount = constraint.getValue();
  }
```

After this I start iterating over a list using forEach + lambda expression.
Now I have to use this `constraintsAmount` field inside this iteration.

But it says that "`constraintsAmount` might not have been initialized".

How can I get around this one.

Note :

1. I don't want to declare this variable as an instance variable and I certainly don't want to declare and initialize this variable inside the iteration.
2. Since it is a final I cant initialize it and then reuse it inside the if check. So wanted to check what is the work around.

Comment: Question - what happens when `constraint` isn't present?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes I understand why it is giving the error, since if constraint is not present variable wont be initialized. So what is the work around to solve this.

Comment: @tushR we can't tell you that.  You have to decide what you _want_ to happen when `constraint` isn't present.  You have't told us that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a compiler perspective you need an else block:

```
final String constraintsAmount;
  if(constraint.isPresent()) {
    constraintsAmount = constraint.getValue();
  } else {
    constraintsAmount = ...
  }
```

Even better the ternary operator:

```
final String constraintsAmount = constraint.isPresent() ? constraint.getValue() : ...
```

NOTE: In Java 8 you don't need to declare a variable `final` to use it in a "closure" (inside lambda stuff).

Or maybe you might need to redesign your code altogether. Hard to tell as I don't have enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Assumimg `constraint` is an `Optional<String>` you could do the following:

```
String constraintsAmount = constraint.orElse(<somedefault>);
```

Otherwise if you only want to do something if `constraint` has a value do the following:

```
constraint.ifPresent(constraintsAmount -> { .... });
```

Comment: (in the last case you obviously do not need to declare the `constraintsAmount` variable.)

Answer (score 0):

A local variable has to be explicitly initialized before being used.
Your problem is not specific to the `final` modifier or the use of a lambda expression.

If this condition is `true` :  `if(constraint.isPresent()) {`, 
`constraintsAmount` is initialized. But in the contrary case, it is not initialized.
So if you use this variable, the compiler doesn't accept that.

This code illustrates the problem :

```
  final String constraintsAmount;
  if(constraint.isPresent()) { // initialized
       constraintsAmount = constraint.getValue();
  }
  // if the conditional statement is false, the constraintsAmount var is not initialized

  // So the compiler generates the error 
  // constraintsAmount might not have been initialized

  String lowerCaseString = constraintsAmount.toLowerCase();
```

Either, value `constraintsAmount` in an `else` statement.
Or remove `final` to give a default value to the variable.